# Verify Laravel password hash using C#

Tags: c#, php, laravel

I have an existing Laravel 4 site that stores user login details in the MySql DB.
The password stored as a hash using....

```
Hash::make()
```

There is now a new separate site being made that will utilise the same user logins in the same db.  This site will be built in  C#.

How can I in C# verify a user's login credentials when the password hash in the DB was created using Laravel?

Comment: See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing), laravel behind the scenes uses bcrypt to hash passwords. Forget about using same database, force users to create new passwords - email them link to insert new password hash it using C# however you want and from there use this information to sign users in.

Comment: Unfortunately forcing users to create a new password is not option my scenario. I'll have a look into the bcrypt thing though

Comment: You mentioned L4 here is correct link https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#storing-passwords and from API reference here is code that you need to check out https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php#L21

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but this worked for me:

Install package

[image]

Then you just import the library in the .cs file

[image]

And in a function for example "LOGIN" after making the query to the `DB` we verify if the passwords are the same as in the image where the first parameter is the password that you enter in the `textbox` and the other is the one that returns the consult.

[image]

I made a query to the DB with the username,
You can use the field you want, mail, names, surnames, etc.

> **Sorry if I'm not very clear, I'm using a translator, I don't speak English, but I want to contribute to the community, even if it's too
> late, it can help someone like I had to investigate to make this
> work.**